# How do I make jQuery UI tabs unclickable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI tabs to render tabs. I need to make the tabs unclickable so that when a tab is clicked, nothing happens. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

you can disable the tabs

```
 //getter
    var disabled = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "disabled" );
    //setter
    $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", [1, 2] );
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs